# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string 4

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Not certain what I need to do here ... I have a SQL statement in a `SqlCommand` that works:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from fb_results where fb_date between '20130501' and '20130629' and fb_response = 'Yes' Order by fb_date, fb_login", conn);
```

Now I want to substitute a query string parameter for the hard coded date.

Here is my code:

```
 string arg1 = Request.QueryString["date1"];
 string arg2 = Request.QueryString["date2"];
 DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(arg1);
 DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(arg2);
 string cvt1 = "'"+dt1.Year.ToString() + dt1.Month.ToString() + dt1.Day.ToString()+"'";
 string cvt2 = "'"+dt2.Year.ToString() + dt2.Month.ToString() + dt2.Day.ToString()+"'";
 string qry = "select * from fb_results where fb_date between " + cvt1 + " and " + cvt2;

 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetConnectionString("feedback"));
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
 //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from fb_results where fb_date between '20130501' and '20130629' and fb_response = 'Yes' Order by fb_date, fb_login", conn);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 da.Fill(ds);

 GridView1.DataSource = ds;
 GridView1.DataBind();

 conn.Close();
```

I am getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What can I do to correct this? Thank you for any assistance.
Regards,

Comment: What value is in `arg1` and `arg2`?

Comment: We'll need to know what values are in arg1 and arg2 to give you an answer. Additionally, you can save yourself some time in the "ToString" calls by changing it to this:

dt1.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Convert.ToDateTime(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) expects a format supported by the current culture. If you're using `yyyyMMdd`, this is most likely NOT a supported format. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) for expected formats.

I would like to add to this and say you should definitely use a parameterised query as suggested by Romoku.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) and [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx).

```
DateTime dt1;
DateTime dt2;

if(!DateTime.TryParse(arg1, out dt1) && !DateTime.TryParse(arg2, out dt2))
{
    // Handle error
}

const string query = "select * from fb_results where fb_date between @from and @to";

var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", dt1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", dt2);
```

Comment: Great recommendation but doesn't actually solve the problem. The parse will fail due to invalid date formats.

Comment: He'll probably need to use one of the `DateTime.TryParse` overrides.

Answer (score 0):

dt1.Month.ToString()

If the month number is 1 digit, and you concatenate, you could end up with a date like this:

2013624  (notice that you need 06, not just 6).

Instead you could try:

```
(dt1.Year * 10000 + dt1.Month * 100 + dt1.Day).ToString()
```

Comment: he wrote them while initiating them

Comment: @MDMalik, I noticed that after posting, so I changed my answer.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't taken into account the need for zero padding on the dates. The code to construct `cvt1` and `cvt2` should look something like this:

```
string cvt1 = "'"+dt1.Year.ToString("0000") + dt1.Month.ToString("00") + dt1.Day.ToString("00")+"'";
string cvt2 = "'"+dt2.Year.ToString("0000") + dt2.Month.ToString("00") + dt2.Day.ToString("00")+"'";
```

Comment: Thank you James, I do appreciate all of your help!